# Why did Shri Krishna show his power to everyone

Tags: krishna

I am trying to understand something about Hinduism particularly Shri Krishna. I want to understand why he would show how powerful he is. I guess I am looking at this in terms of today. If someone said they were an incarnation of Krishna and showed the powers that they had and proved it. Then people would come and ask for favors. Wouldn't it be the same then. If not why not and if so then why did he show the infinite power that he has?

Comment: Krishna didn't show his power for sake of showing.  He showed his true forms (like Viswaroopa Darshana) to only his **true** devotees.

Comment: I would say I agree but everyone in the Mahabharat know that he is SHRI Krishna and that he has powers that are infinite so I guess the question that I have is why/how do they know that? and why does krishna let that knowledge be public?

Comment: Open display of power acts as a deterrence and reverence.

Comment: Would you like to give me example(s) where Krishna showed His powers?